# Does Meta Refresh work during page load?

Tags: html, http, refresh, meta-tags

Page **A** has a meta refresh to redirect to another page, **C**,  after a certain amount of time (time **T**).

From page **A** a link is clicked that takes a long time to load, longer than time **T**, and would eventually load another page; **B**.

Will the meta refresh on page **A** cause the page to be re-directed to **C**, or will the processing of the link override the meta refresh, eventually loading page **B**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click a link to page B before page A redirects to C, you will get page B.  If you open the link to page B in a new tab, then you'll get page C in the first tab (after the redirect), and page B in the second tab (the loading of page B will of course not wait for the redirect of A -> C).

Answer (score 1):

Meta Refresh is work when the all of document loaded completely (even you set the timing for 0 second), so when you click another link before it's redirected the actions is what was you clicked.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide a related source that says Meta Refresh works when all of the document loaded completely?